# MSSQL Distinct error in ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pagination

I'm using both MySQL & MSSQL in my project, I've limit condtn, distinct and combine the my query for pagination.

MYSQL Query's are working fine but MSSQL Query have an Error when am using distinct in LIMIT query.

MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  p_rework
,                p_approved 
,                pf_id
,                pf_plan 
,                pf_ver
,                pf_createdby
,                pf_createdon createdon
,                pf_updatedby
,                pf_updatedon
,                pf_approvedby
,                pf_approvedon
,                0 p_runs
,                '' runname
,                '' runstatus
,                '' scheduledon
,                '' runon 
FROM             planinfo a
,                plans b 
WHERE            a.pf_id = b.p_id 
            AND  pf_project='proj001' 
            AND  p_approved IN(0,3,4) 
GROUP BY         pf_id
,                pf_createdon
,                pf_updatedon
,                pf_plan
,                pf_ver
,                pf_createdby
,                pf_updatedby
,                pf_approvedby
,                pf_approvedon
,                b.p_createdon
,                b.p_approved
,                p_rework  
ORDER BY         pf_id  DESC  
LIMIT            0,5
```

The Above MYSQL query working fine but MSSQL Query Not working
MSSQL QUERY:

```
select      * 
from        (
                select  ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY  pf_id  DESC) AS Row 
                ,       distinct p_rework
                ,       p_approved 
                ,       pf_id
                ,       pf_plan 
                ,       pf_ver
                ,       pf_createdby
                ,       pf_createdon createdon
                ,       pf_updatedby
                ,       pf_updatedon
                ,       pf_approvedby
                ,       pf_approvedon
                ,       0 p_runs
                ,       '' runname
                ,       '' runstatus
                ,       '' scheduledon
                ,       '' runon 
                FROM    planinfo a
                ,       plans b 
                WHERE   a.pf_id = b.p_id 
                    AND pf_project='proj001' 
                    AND p_approved In(0,3,4) 
                GROUP BY pf_id 
                ,        pf_createdon
                ,        pf_updatedon
                ,        pf_plan
                ,        pf_ver
                ,        pf_createdby
                ,        pf_updatedby 
                ,        pf_approvedby
                ,        pf_approvedon
                ,        b.p_createdon
                ,        b.p_approved
                ,        p_rework
            ) as temp 
 WHERE  row between 0 and 5
```

MSSQL ERROR IS:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.
```

Without distinct i tried and its working but pagination is not working and i want to display distinct value also.

How to modify my query with distinct??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` operates on the entire result set, you can't select `distinct` for some of your selected attributes. As such, `distinct` should be first after the select: `SELECT DISTINCT {Some attributes}`.

Also please see my edit of your question, isn't that a lot easier to read?
Further, you should use `join` syntax: `select * from a join b on a.id = b.id`
Lastly, you're using `distinct` as well as `group by`, this is unnecessary as they both result in the same set. You can't do a `distinct` on `row_number` since it is distinct by default.

**edit**

Almost forgot, your `group by` is wrong anyway: in most DBMS's (as far as I know all, except for mysql) all attributes in your select, which are not in an aggregate function **have** to be in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH t AS
(
        select  distinct ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY  pf_id  DESC) AS Row
        ,       p_rework
        ,       p_approved 
        ,       pf_id
        ,       pf_plan 
        ,       pf_ver
        ,       pf_createdby
        ,       pf_createdon createdon
        ,       pf_updatedby
        ,       pf_updatedon
        ,       pf_approvedby
        ,       pf_approvedon
        ,       0 p_runs
        ,       '' runname
        ,       '' runstatus
        ,       '' scheduledon
        ,       '' runon 
        FROM    planinfo a
        ,       plans b 
        WHERE   a.pf_id = b.p_id 
            AND pf_project='proj001' 
            AND p_approved In(0,3,4) 
        GROUP BY pf_id 
        ,        pf_createdon
        ,        pf_updatedon
        ,        pf_plan
        ,        pf_ver
        ,        pf_createdby
        ,        pf_updatedby 
        ,        pf_approvedby
        ,        pf_approvedon
        ,        b.p_createdon
        ,        b.p_approved
        ,        p_rework
)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.Row between 0 and 5
```